# std::time(0) performance

Tags: c++, performance

I was wondering what the performance implications are of using std::time(0) to seed random number generators. I assume that it's a system call (if not please correct me), which generally isn't the best option regarding performance. Assuming std::time(0) is used many times throughout a program, will there be severe performance implications if any?

P.S. I'm more curious than anything, as currently there aren't any performance issues.

Comment: If you are using it frequently to seed a random number generator, you might have other problems, such as not getting particularly random numbers.

Comment: That's some consensus on this question.

Comment: I'm surprised no one's responded with a super-efficient RNG reseeding algorithm, just to be contrary!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reseeding the RNG should be a rather rare event, so I don't think you need to be concerned about performance.  If you *are* reseeding frequently enough to cause a performance issue, you might want to rethink your approach -- you may be doing more harm than good.

Comment: I use boost::mt19937, and seed it with the current time. However, it is created in each function that random numbers are generated in, and these functions are called multiple times. I considered moving the seeding out somewhere else so I only do it once, but there haven't been any performance issues so I haven't bothered.

Comment: But then you are probably generating the same sequence of random numbers each time that function is called multiple times during the same second!

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't even though of that.

Comment: @Person: Understood!  But the quality of the random number sequences you're generating might suffer, due to the repeated reseeding.  Depending on your application, that may, or may not, justify refactoring the RNG initialization to occur outside the functions that use it.

Answer (score 3):

My old probability/statistics professor would tell you that if you seed your random generator more than once, you're doing it wrong. It doesn't get better when seeded again and again. It get worse! If that was for cryptographic applications it would be a major weakness, and even if it's not, there's no reason to.

So in short, yes, it's a system call, but you should only seed once, so it's completely absorbed in the rest of the computations.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't see any performance issues doing this, even if you call `time(0)` frequently (note that its resolution is generally in seconds, though, so there's not much reason to call it more than once per second for using it for your purpose).

If it *does* look like it is causing performance problems, something is very, very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You typically only need to seed a random generator occasionally (usually only once), so it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy your curiosity, I'd like to point out that `std::time()` is *usually* a system call.  However, I do know that in some cases, the OS may use approximations based on something like the hardware clock-tick counter (`rdtsc` instruction on x86) if the last call was executed recently.  This is very efficient in the expected case, and IMHO it's not any less accurate, given that avoiding a system call results in much more deterministic behavior.

But yeah, re-seeding your RNG shouldn't *ever* be the bottleneck in your application.